# Will scheduled task run if the user is not opening the application?

Tags: javascript

The situation:

I have a program that records student's payments, (made entirely with HTML, CSS and javascript), I would like it to calculate the amount of students that stopped the lessons, automatically, around the end of the month (by automatically I mean without the user having to press any buttons to get that info).

My question is:

If for example I schedule the function to run on the 29 of every month, and that day the user does not open the program, does the function get executed anyway or not?

The program is an off line program, made to be downloaded once and run always, no need to connect again to the web if the user decides it.

I would do something like:

```
var thisMoment = new Date(),//creates a date object

currentDay = thisMoment.getDate(); //this would give me the day at that moment.

if(currentDay == 29) {  }//code to be executed here
```

I know I could just try it, but I would have to wait for a day, or rewrite the code to schedule something some minutes ahead, but I would miss all the juicy information you are probably going to share here hahaha.

Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: Is your personal computer running Windows?

Comment: Unless there's some sort of server-side component, your HTML app effectively ceases to exist as soon as the user closes it. Nothing will happen if it's not open.

Comment: @Froopy, yes, it is. But I will use this program on android too.

Comment: @JoeClay, I see. Ok, I was afraid of that hahah. I will find another way then. Thank you. :) You could make it an answer so I vote it as the right one.

Comment: Seems like you have approx 0.001% knowledge of how web works

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly, make it 0,0001%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there's some sort of server-side component, your HTML app effectively ceases to exist as soon as the user closes it. Nothing will happen if it's not open.

To do this kind of thing, you will either need a server application that's continuously running, or some sort of [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job that runs an application/script on the server at the desired time. Then, you will need to have your frontend application communicate with this server, most likely through some kind of REST API.